# Binary Search Tree for employee manager search

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I want to write a java program to arrange the given employee ID in a Binary Search Tree format and then find the immediate manager of any given employee in the organization.

### Employee Binary Tree:

[image: Employee Binary Tree]

Input Format

- The first line should contain the number of employees "n" to be inserted in the Tree
- The second line should contain the employee ID for which we need to find the immediate manager.
- The next "n" lines should contain the employee IDs to form the binary search Tree.

### Sample:

[image: Sample Output]

### Below is the code with which I have intialized the tree successfully. I need help on how to search the parent node for a given child node.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class BinarySearchTree { 

    /* Class containing left and right child of current node and key value*/
    class Node { 
        int data; 
        int key; 
        Node left, right; 
  
        public Node(int item) { 
            key = item; 
            left = right = null; 
        } 
    } 
    // Root of BST 
    Node root; 

    // Constructor 
    BinarySearchTree() { 
        root = null; 
    } 

    // This method mainly calls insertRec() 
    void insert(int key) { 
    root = insertRec(root, key); 
    } 
    
    /* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
    Node insertRec(Node root, int key) { 

        /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
        if (root == null) { 
            root = new Node(key); 
            return root; 
        } 

        /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
        if (key < root.key) 
            root.left = insertRec(root.left, key); 
        else if (key > root.key) 
            root.right = insertRec(root.right, key); 

        /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
        return root; 
    } 

    // This method mainly calls InorderRec() 
    void inorder() { 
    inorderRec(root); 
    } 

    // A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
    void inorderRec(Node root) { 
        if (root != null) { 
            inorderRec(root.left); 
            System.out.println(root.key); 
            inorderRec(root.right); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(); 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        //int sch = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {
            tree.insert(sc.nextInt()); 
        }
        tree.inorder(); 
    }
}
```

---

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work in this way, You should tell what exactly is your problem, what do you want, and what you've tried. We're here to solve problems in code, not to write all of that from scratch.

Comment: @MuhammadVakili The problem that I am facing is I don't know how to create a Binary Tree in Java. As I am new to programming. So any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: @MuhammadVakili Can you help now?

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet? I just searched for ___java build binary tree___ and found this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree According to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users): _Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer_

Comment: @Abra So currently I have created the tree as per the code mentioned in my question. However I am unable to search the parent for a particular node. The example mentioned in the link you provided, does not have a parent search example which I am looking for.

Comment: @Abra Thank you so much. Appreciate your time and effort that you've put, to not only send me the solution but also the beautiful explanation that you have provided along with that. I can see that the method for search returns the employee and manager values which you are printing in the printf statement. Can you please tell me how can I print only the manager value (i.e 77) only in the print statement? I tried editing the print statement but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a recursive method, the first thing you need is a condition that terminates the recursion. In your case there are two conditions, as follows.

1. You find the employee that you are searching for.
2. You reach the end of the tree.

The recursion needs to terminate if either of the above conditions is true. In your case, terminating the recursion means the method must return a value.

If the terminating condition is not true, the method needs to call itself but with different values for the method parameters.

Here is my recursive search method. More explanation appears after the code.

```java
int search(int employee, int manager, Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        if (employee == node.key) {
            return manager;
        }
        manager = node.key;
        if (employee < node.key) {
            return search(employee, manager, node.left);
        }
        else {
            return search(employee, manager, node.right);
        }
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The method parameters are as follows:

1. employee - the employee to search for
2. manager - the manager of the next parameter
3. node - a node in the tree that will be checked to see if its `key` is the employee we are searching for

We start searching at the root of the tree and traverse down through the tree nodes. Hence the initial call to the method, which would probably be in method `main()` would be:

```java
tree.search(sch, -1, tree.root)
```

According to your sample data, `sch` is 55. Note that in the initial call, the manager is `-1` since the root of the tree does not have a manager. So if `sch` equals the root `key`, the method will return `-1`.

Since we know that the `key` in the left child of a node is lower and the right child's `key` is higher, we don't have to search every node. So the method calls itself with the relevant child node. Also we save the current `key` because if the child node's `key` is the one we are searching for, then this node's `key` is the manager.

If the `node` parameter in method `search()` is null, that means we have reached the end of the tree which means we have not found the value we are searching for. The value `-1` (minus one) is a convention for a value that indicates that the search failed. Method [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) in class `String` is an example of a method also using that convention.

Finally, I used the code you posted in your question. I only added the above method as well as a call to that method from method `main()`. I added the initial call to method `search()` as the last line in method `main()`.

For completeness, here is the entire code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearchTree {
    class Node {
        int key;
        Node left, right;

        public Node(int item) {
            key = item;
            left = right = null;
        }
    }

    // Root of BST
    Node root;

    // Constructor
    BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    // This method mainly calls insertRec()
    void insert(int key) {
        root = insertRec(root, key);
    }

    /* A recursive function to insert a new key in BST */
    Node insertRec(Node root, int key) {

        /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
        if (root == null) {
            root = new Node(key);
            return root;
        }

        /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
        if (key < root.key)
            root.left = insertRec(root.left, key);
        else if (key > root.key)
            root.right = insertRec(root.right, key);

        /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
        return root;
    }

    // This method mainly calls InorderRec()
    void inorder() {
        inorderRec(root);
    }

    // A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST
    void inorderRec(Node root) {
        if (root != null) {
            inorderRec(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.key);
            inorderRec(root.right);
        }
    }

    // The method I added.
    int search(int employee, int manager, Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            if (employee == node.key) {
                return manager;
            }
            manager = node.key;
            if (employee < node.key) {
                return search(employee, manager, node.left);
            }
            else {
                return search(employee, manager, node.right);
            }
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int sch = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            tree.insert(sc.nextInt());
        }
        tree.inorder();
        System.out.printf("Manager is %d%n", tree.search(sch, -1, tree.root)); // changed this line to print only manager.
    }
}
```

Comment: @RajarshiSikdar I edited the java code as you requested in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873932/binary-search-tree-for-employee-manager-search#comment111563560_62873932). See the last line of method `main()`.